# Is it possible to move my Minecraft saved game from PS4 to XBOX One?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, ps4, xbox-one

My friend and I are switching from PS4 to Xbox One. We have a Minecraft world saved that we have been working on for over a year and would really like to move it to Xbox One, however it doesn't seem possible. Is it even possible?

Answer (score -1):

Sony (PlayStation) and Microsoft (Xbox) are rivals, so no. Even if you use your own methods of some sort, it is **impossible.**
Sorry... I get how you feel.